# Diff values by group in data frame

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` like this:

```
head(MatrixVertice2011,35)
     values        ind
5  10.82000 2011-01-03
6  11.75000 2011-01-03
7  10.84048 2011-01-04
8  11.79000 2011-01-04
9  10.87095 2011-01-05
10 11.84000 2011-01-05
11 10.88928 2011-01-06
12 11.88000 2011-01-06
13 10.92000 2011-01-07
14 12.03000 2011-01-07
19 10.93984 2011-01-10
20 12.17000 2011-01-10
...
33 11.10000 2011-01-17
34 12.38000 2011-01-17
35 11.11000 2011-01-18
36 12.32000 2011-01-18
37 11.15000 2011-01-19
38 12.30000 2011-01-19
39 11.14000 2011-01-20
40 12.30000 2011-01-20
41 11.15000 2011-01-21
42 12.35000 2011-01-21
47 11.14000 2011-01-24
48 12.40000 2011-01-24
49 11.14000 2011-01-26
50 12.51000 2011-01-26
51 11.14000 2011-01-27
```

I need to do lag differences.  I need to do this according to the dates

When I'm in 2011-01-03 I would differentiate 6th - 5th, and thus, step to the next date and so on, respecting the date.

Could you help me to implement a code/function or a hint, that would do this?

When I do:

```
MatrixSPREAD<-diff(MatrizVertice2011$values)
```

This command doesn't respect the date, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(MatrixVertice2011)[, list(diff=diff(values)), by=ind]

          ind    diff
1: 2011-01-03 0.93000
2: 2011-01-04 0.94952
3: 2011-01-05 0.96905
...
12: 2011-01-24 1.26000
13: 2011-01-26 1.37000
```

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

MatrixVertice2011 %>% group_by(ind) %>%
  summarise(diff = diff(values)[1])
```

With base R:

```
aggregate(values ~ ind, FUN=diff, data=MatrixVertice2011)
```